# Создание собственных координат внутри Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо задать собственную систему координат в `Canvas`. Значения `X` и значения `Y` не будут одинакового типа. По `X` хочу сделать тип `DateTime`, по `Y` сделать `double`. Как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В canvas всегда будут координаты double.

А так, используй конвертеры. 
Если хочешь в xaml выставлять значения и привязываться, то ищи инфу по IValueConverter. 
Если в коде, то просто статичный метод-конвертер напиши.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Просто буду относительно имеющихся координат записывать свои собственные, конвертируя их в данном масштабе